# what is the meaning of " to be of something"

Tags: grammar, sentence-structure

I've seen some sentences using this structure, but I cannot find it how and when it is used.
for example : having a traditional meal **is of importance** in many social situation.
another example is " **be of use**". What does it mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess, in aspect of the meaning **is of importance** and **is important** are the same. The only difference is that the first one is more academic and rhetorical and can be used in formal written text or speech. You can even use `of utmost importance` to emphasize.